# Show hidden div with css

Tags: php, jquery, css, hide, show-hide

I have a php program which load 3 css files like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css.css" media="screen"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/printer.css" media="print"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/spoken.css" media="speech"/>
```

I have jquery set up to hide everything from my screen except the h1 tags, when one clicks this h1 tag the associated h2, h3 and divs show up

my problem is I need everything to show up when I go the the printpreview in chrome or firefox

Comment: do you use jquery.hide() ? Which can you modify: HTML? Javascript? CSS? for that kind of things id use toggleClass to toggle hiding/displaying properties from your CSS rules.

Comment: I use $('<tag name>').hide or the .show()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `$("*").show()` should display everything on page except elements with visibility:hidden.

Comment: but how do you check whether you are in a print preview?

Comment: Try to use "media" setting for CSS. Review http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp and make CSS like span, input, a  .... {display:inline}, div, table ... {display:block}

Answer (score 1):

i think you are going to have to have a print previous option/button/page/version that displays all the elements for users to actually print... i dont think you are gonna be able to set a listener to the event file->print preview